# Insert statements not working in Supabase when hosting Spring Boot API to Render

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, render, sql-insert, supabase

I am practicing Spring Boot REST API and PostgreSQL. I create a service to crawl data from a website each 30 min and save data into PostgreSQL. Everything locally is working okay for both local database or Supabase database. Problem shows up when I host API to Render. Crawling is still working and I can see message but database is not updated. API is working normally (I think so because I test it through swagger-ui). Please help me.
Here is the messages of API on Render.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */30 * * * ?")
public void articleCrawl() {
    try {
        // Add to a list to set order
        List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
        // Connect to Jsoup
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(Constants.LASTEST_URL).get();
        // Find news wrapped in boxes in the main section
        Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("list__listing-main")// section__middle-news section__mn-main
                .first()
                .getElementsByClass("box-category-item");
        // Iterate each element
        for (Element e : elements) {
            Article article = new Article();
            // Find slug
            String url = e.child(1).attr("href");
            String slug = url.replaceAll("^/|\\.htm$", "");
            // Check existing article
            if (!articleService.existsBySlug(slug)) {
                article.setTitle(e.child(1).attr("title"));
                article.setUrl(url);
                article.setSlug(slug);
                // Static image or gif
                String thumbnail = e.child(1).child(0).attr("src") != null
                        ? e.child(1).child(0).attr("src") : e.child(1).child(0).attr("poster");
                article.setThumbnail(thumbnail);
                article.setOpening(e.getElementsByClass("box-category-sapo").text()); // in p tag
                // Crawl detail of article
                articleDetailCrawl(article);
                // Add to list
                articles.add(article);
            }
        }
        // Reverse the list to make the newest article to the last
        Collections.reverse(articles);
        // Add to database
        for (Article a : articles) {
            articleService.save(a);
        }
        System.out.println("Crawl articles at " + new Date());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Connection is working well because I use local API smoothly.